# Uninstalling .NET framework 1, 2 and 3

Tags: .net-framework, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need all Microsoft .NET Framework versions?](https://superuser.com/questions/252614/do-i-need-all-microsoft-net-framework-versions)

Is this safe to uninstall older NET. Frameworks? I'm currently using the v4. Can I uninstall the 3 previous one that eat space on my laptop, or, this action will break the latest version (which, in fact, relies on some pieces in the previous ones, for instance) ?

Comment: Do they really take up that much space?

Comment: Not that much, but I have no more space left, so it's an option to consider if it's not armful. In fact I have the same question about Visual Studio 2008 and 2005... Can I unistal them ? :-)

Comment: +1 for asking this, i also want to know

Comment: Are you really asking if you can uninstall Visual Studio 2008 and 2005 from your own machine?  The answer is you can do anything you want.

Comment: "exact duplicate"... You must be joking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, however note that if you are doing development work in IIS and have application pools configured to use previous versions then strange behaviour may happen.

The overhead is not great, however, so unless you're *really* short of space I'd not bother.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to uninstall all of them (in the opposite order - 4, 3.5, 3, 2, 1.1, 1.0) and then install v4.